# Access list at index from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In my program I have a tree-like architecture of objects that I need to access from the QML. I cannot figure out how can I create a `Q_PROPERTY` getter function, that would allow me to access the item at the Index of my choosing. The function looks like this in the C++ part:

```
/**
 * @brief   Risk object getter function.
 * @param   index: The index of the risk from the \ref m_risks container.
 * @return  Pointer to the risk object if \p index is valid. Otherwise 0.
 */
CRiskData* CVessel::getRisk(const int index)
{
    if (index >= m_risks.length())
        return nullptr;

    return m_risks[index];
}
```

But it seems that this QML <-> Qt property communication system only allows a getter that has no input parameters. I tried to define it like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(CRiskData* risk READ getRisk)
```

I get a compiler error that no matching function is found for:

```
moc_cvessel.cpp:122: error: no matching function for call to 'CVessel::getRisk()'
         case 0: *reinterpret_cast< CRiskData**>(_v) = _t->getRisk(); break;
                                                                   ^
```

So MOC created the function with no input arguments...
Is there any way around this? The goal is to be able to access each element of an object from the QML side in a hierarchical way.

Comment: You can use `Q_INVOKABLE` to make it a function that can have arguments, however, this might not be handy with regards to binding, but that cannot be examined since that part of code is not given

Comment: @Amfasis thank you for answer. I think this will work, will try to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question, I think you should use something with related to MVVM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) or MVC. So you should create your own C++ model that you expose to QML, by subclassing `QAbstractItemModel`. In this model, create a `Q_INVOKABLE` method in your list model:

cvessel.hpp:

```
#ifndef CVESSEL_HPP
#define CVESSEL_HPP

#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QList>
class CRiskData;

class CVessel: public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        CVessel(QObject * parent = nullptr);
        Q_INVOKABLE CRiskData* getRisk(const int index);
        static void declareQML();

        // QAbstractItemModel subclassing & rest of the header

    protected:
        QList<CRiskData *> m_risks;
};

#endif    // CVESSEL_HPP
```

cvessel.cpp:

```
#include "cvessel.hpp"
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include "criskdata.hpp"

CVessel::CVessel(QObject * parent = nullptr) :
    QAbstractItemModel(parent),
    m_risks()
{}

CRiskData* CVessel::getRisk(const int index);
{
    if (index >= m_risks.length())
        return nullptr;

    return m_risks[index];
}

void CVessel::declareQML() {
    qmlRegisterType<CVessel>("Bremen", 3, 14, "CVessel");
}

// Rest of implementation
```

RiskComponent.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import Bremen 3.14

Item {
    id: risk_component

    // ...

    TreeItem {
        id: the_tree
        model: CVessel {}

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    function usingARisk(riskIndex) {
        var risk = risk_component.the_tree.model.getRisk(riskIndex)

        // Using your risk on the QML side. For Example:
        console.log(qsTr("Risk level: %1").arg(risk.level))
    }

    // ...

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "criskdata.hpp"
#include "cvessel.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //...

    CRiskData::declareQML();    // Of course if you use it on the QML side.
    CVessel::declareQML();

    //...

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    int res = engine.rootObjects().isEmpty() ? -1 : app.exec();

    //...

    return res;
}
```

For further information about model subclassing, please have a look at [the "*Model/View Programming*" page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) in Qt documentation, especially at [the "*Model Subclassing Reference*" section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference).

Comment: Why did you subclass `QAbstractItemModel` here exactly? Is it necessary?

Comment: I have just updated my answer with answers to your comment questions.

Comment: Thank you for the update. My point was that the "to qml" exposure functionality can be achieved with sublasing just Qobject. Thats why I asked why is it for exactly.

Comment: For the "to QML" exposure, you have to: 1°) subclass `QObject`, 2°) provide a default constructor and 3°) calling `qmlRegisterType<>();` in the `main();` entry point. For further information, have a look at this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html

Comment: Thats right! Thats why I wonder for ehat end the QAbstra tItemModel is used?